# Problem in code that must not repeat the same number in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function

I've written this function that returns a time(number )that must not exist in the same day in the database which means that the same time must not be repeated but when I execute it the time(number) is repeated
can you help me sort this one out?

screen shots of the tables 
https://files.fm/u/9aw9yc8x

note: the table is empty and it will be filled when the entire code is executed I have just posted the function that must not repeat the time.

```
function checkTime($className,$day,$conn){
    global $numberLimet,$Daily,$UserLimt,$exist;
    $sqlHoure = "SELECT * from schedule WHERE classname='".$className."'";
    $hourQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlHoure);
    $h = array();
    while ($hour = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hourQuery)){
        $h[$hour['hour']] = $hour['day1'];
        // array_search();
    }
    $number = rand(1,7);
    if(array_search($day,$h) && array_key_exists($number,$h)){
        return 'error';
    }else{
        if($hour['hour'] != $number && $hour['day1']  != $day){
            $numberLimet++;
            if($numberLimet == $Daily){
                $UserLimt = 1;
                $FristAdd = false;
                echo("UserLimt" . $UserLimt);
                return 'errorLimit';
            }else{
                return $number;
            }
        }else{

        }
    }
    return $h;
}
```

Comment: a glimpse at your tables would help quite a bit... as it is know, the question and code don't help much in clearing up what you need

Comment: Consistently formatting your code is important so that both other people can understand it, and so that _you_ can too.

Comment: ok i will add a screen shot of the database and i will add the entire code

Comment: screen shots of the tables https://files.fm/u/9aw9yc8x

Comment: If you're looking for something that isn't to be repeated, why don't you first check to see if it exists first with `num_rows()` or `COUNT(x)`? If this is what the question's about.